# Python ipykernel not installing with Errno 2

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

Trying to run code in VSC and I get the popup to install `ipykernel`

[image]

Once I click "install", I get the following error in my terminal
[image]

I updated Python and installed the newest version 3.9.0 and selected the checkbox "Add to PATH". I checked the Environment Variables and there is a PATH for python. How do I fix this?

Comment: You can try to manually install the kernel "ipykernel" using "pip" in the currently selected VSCode environment. (pip install ipykernel)

Comment: I did try that and get the error ```Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python38\python.exe"  "C:\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe" install ipykernel': The system cannot find the file specified. ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the output for the install command it looks like the slashes are missing in the "Can't open file" line. Which looks similar to this issue here:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13005

Are you possibly using Git Bash or WSL Bash for your terminal in VSCode? If so it looks like changing that terminal might be a solution to the install issue.

Comment: Changing my terminal to command prompt and then python solved it.